# SSE optimization of sum of squared differences

Tags: c++, image-processing, optimization, sse, simd

I've recently found that my program spend most time in the following simple function:

```
void SumOfSquaredDifference(
    const uint8_t * a, size_t aStride, const uint8_t * b, size_t bStride, 
    size_t width, size_t height, uint64_t * sum)
{
    *sum = 0;
    for(size_t row = 0; row < height; ++row)
    {
        int rowSum = 0;
        for(size_t col = 0; col < width; ++col)
        {
            int d = a[col] - b[col];
            rowSum += d*d;
        }
        *sum += rowSum;
        a += aStride;
        b += bStride;
    }
}
```

This function finds a sum of squared difference of two 8-bit gray images. 
I think that there is the way to improve its performance with using SSE, but I don't have an experience in this area. 
Could anybody help me?

Comment: Before you start optimising this by hand, you need to check that your compiler is not already generating vectorized code. Make sure you have optimisation and SIMD enabled and check the generated code for SSE instructions, otherwise you may waste time on a fool's errand. (BTW, please specify what CPU hardware, OS and compiler you are using.)

Comment: Your outer loop seems useless. Is that a mistake?

Comment: @A.S.H: I know it looks odd, but he's bumping the `a`, `b` pointers on each row iteration.

Comment: @PaulR ah, you're right, good catch!

Comment: Clang and GCC auto-vectorize this, but not in a nice way (using `vpmulld` which is low-throughput)

Comment: I would expect the compiler to hesitate about using SSE. `height`, `width`, `aStride` and `bStride` are all runtime arguments. This means that neither the begin nor the end of each row may be suitably aligned for SSE (16 bytes)

Comment: Depending on your expected usage, it might be worth optimizing the case where aStride==bStride==width (in which case you can use a single single loop from 0 to height*width).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, you can improve your code. 
This an example of optimization of your function with using SSE2:

```
const __m128i Z = _mm_setzero_si128();
const size_t A = sizeof(__m128i);

inline __m128i SquaredDifference(__m128i a, __m128i b)
{
    const __m128i aLo = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(a, Z);
    const __m128i bLo = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(b, Z);
    const __m128i dLo = _mm_sub_epi16(aLo, bLo);

    const __m128i aHi = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(a, Z);
    const __m128i bHi = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(b, Z);
    const __m128i dHi = _mm_sub_epi16(aHi, bHi);

    return _mm_add_epi32(_mm_madd_epi16(dLo, dLo), _mm_madd_epi16(dHi, dHi));
}

inline __m128i HorizontalSum32(__m128i a)
{
    return _mm_add_epi64(_mm_unpacklo_epi32(a, Z), _mm_unpackhi_epi32(a, Z));
}

inline uint64_t ExtractSum64(__m128i a)
{
    uint64_t  _a[2];
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)_a, a);
    return _a[0] + _a[1];
}

void SumOfSquaredDifference(
    const uint8_t *a, size_t aStride, const uint8_t *b, size_t bStride, 
    size_t width, size_t height, uint64_t * sum)
{
    assert(width%A == 0 && width < 0x10000);
    __m128i fullSum = Z;
    for(size_t row = 0; row < height; ++row)
    {
        __m128i rowSum = Z;
        for(size_t col = 0; col < width; col += A)
        {
            const __m128i a_ = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(a + col));
            const __m128i b_ = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(b + col)); 
            rowSum = _mm_add_epi32(rowSum, SquaredDifference(a_, b_));
        }
        fullSum = _mm_add_epi64(fullSum, HorizontalSum32(rowSum));
        a += aStride;
        b += bStride;
    }
    *sum = ExtractSum64(fullSum);
}
```

This example is a few simplified (it doesn't work if the image width isn't multiple of 16).
Full version of the algorithm is [here](https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd/blob/master/src/Simd/SimdSse2SquaredDifferenceSum.cpp).

And some magic from [SSSE3](https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd/blob/master/src/Simd/SimdSsse3SquaredDifferenceSum.cpp) version:

```
const __m128i K_1FF = _mm_set1_epi16(0x1FF);

inline __m128i SquaredDifference(__m128i a, __m128i b)
{
    const __m128i lo = _mm_maddubs_epi16(_mm_unpacklo_epi8(a, b), K_1FF);
    const __m128i hi = _mm_maddubs_epi16(_mm_unpackhi_epi8(a, b), K_1FF);
    return _mm_add_epi32(_mm_madd_epi16(lo, lo), _mm_madd_epi16(hi, hi));
}
```

The magic description (see [_mm_maddubs_epi16](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514017(v=vs.120).aspx)):

```
K_1FF -> {-1, 1, -1, 1, ...};
_mm_unpacklo_epi8(a, b) -> {a0, b0, a1, b1, ...};
_mm_maddubs_epi16(_mm_unpacklo_epi8(a, b), K_1FF) -> {b0 - a0, b1 - a1, ...};
```

Comment: What's going on in that SSSE3 version?

Comment: Thanks for the Library link! Its awesome!

Comment: It is close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

GCC has switches that encourage it to vectorize the code. For example, the `-mfma` switch gives me about 25% speed increase on simple loops like this, using doubles. I imagine it's even better with 8-bit integers. I prefer that over hand-written optimizations because your code stays readable.

That said, there are a few old tricks that can speed up your loop:

- Don't index, increment your pointer in every loop iteration. You do this in the outer loop, you should do the same in the inner loop. You can create a new pointer before going into the inner loop, so the `+=stride` stays valid.
- Don't assign into the sum pointer inside your loop, use a local variable to accumulate and copy to the output when done. You use `rowSum`, but only in the inner loop. Use that variable across both loops instead.